# No password set in user database

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create signup form adding email field in django from base class UserCreationForm. The code goes as

**form.py**

```
class ussignup(UserCreationForm):
  email=forms.EmailField(required=True)
  first_name=forms.CharField(required=False)
  last_name=forms.CharField(required=False)
  class Meta:
    model=User
    fields=('username','password1','password2','first_name','last_name','email',)
    #fields=('username','password','first_name','last_name','email')

  def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email=self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.first_name=self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        user.last_name=self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

**view.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=ussignup(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/rgsuc')

    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form']=form
    return render_to_response('register.html',args)
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^accounts/signup',signup),
```

**Error**
  output shows the form however the password entered in the field is not saved in database. Thus shows `no password` when viewed from admin and thus unable to login.

Answer (score 0):

ok I finally got it, I need to add

```
user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
```

which I thought it will be saved by django itself however I have overriden the save function thus need to save it also

Answer (score 0):

Or else you could have only changed this (i.e. your class name `ussignup`, instead of the base class `UserCreationForm`) in the method, and it would have worked.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(ussignup, self).save(commit=False)
    user.email=self.cleaned_data["email"]
    user.first_name=self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
    user.last_name=self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Hope this will help.